# Pandas calculate new values of data columns based on current values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have dataframe having base_salary and Currency. I intend to convert all base salaries and currencies that are not in 'USD' to 'USD', and update base_salary. Country column and index is also present as shown below. Basically base_salary and currency are 2 of the 5 columns I am having, but these 2 are column of relevance.
Please suggest how to achieve this without iterating through each row. Also suggest python lib that can help me achieve using conversion from any currency to USD. The one I mentioned below is not suppporting AFN (afgani) and AED currencies.

```
# c.convert(100, 'EUR', 'USD') from euro to usd
from currency_converter import CurrencyConverter
c = CurrencyConverter()
candidate_df = pd.DataFrame( {"base_salary":[5200, 1000, 80, 4000, 0.5, 6036], 
                    "currency":['USD',  'AFN',   'INR',  'EUR',  'USD',  'INR'],
                     "country":['India', 'Egypt', 'Iran', 'Spain', 'India', 'Pakistan']} )
```

I intend to apply something like this

```
from currency_converter import CurrencyConverter
c = CurrencyConverter()

    def f(series):
        return(c.convert(100, 'EUR', 'USD') #from euro to usd)
        # this will convert my currency from currency to 'USD' and return both new salary and currency as 'USD' as new value is in USD

    candidate_df.loc[candidate_df.currency!='USD', 'base_salary', 'currency'] = candidate_df.loc[candidate_df.currency!='USD', 'base_salary', 'currency'].transform(f)
```

in last line I am trying to update both base_salary, currency fields using loc functionality. Please suggest solution

Comment: `loc[candidate_df.currency!='USD', ['base_salary', 'currency']]`?

Comment: Yes, now I am able to send both as series combination to my f functionality. how to return modified base_salary and 'USD' from same f function?